# If I maintain air temperature in a room, but allow humidity to vary, will room objects remain at the same temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, everyday-life, humidity

Let's say I have a room with a HVAC system and I'm trying to keep objects in the room at a constant body temperature. My HVAC system maintains a constant air temperature, but the relative humidity in the room varies by several percent. Would the objects in the room maintain the same constant body temperature as the air temperature, despite the changes in humidity? Assume the objects are relatively small, like marbles, and don't have much heat storage, so they equilibrate in temperature relatively quickly, and also that temperature and humidity conditions are close to typical room temperature values.

Comment: It's possible making the air drier will cause water to evaporate from some objects and evaporatively cool them, at least temporarily.  They will eventually match the air temperature again

Comment: So the objects' body temperatures could temporarily be cooler than air temperature due to evaporation?

Comment: I would say so. Though I don't have specific data to back that up.

Answer (score 0):

With the increase of humidity, the moisture does not effect non-porus objects.  Porus objects on the other hand will absorb the water content of the air.

Comment: You haven't even mentioned temperature here, which is basically the whole question.

Comment: Because the temperature is not affected